# Docker Windows Containers creating unknown l2bridge networks

Tags: docker, windows-server-2016, windows-container

When the Docker service starts on my Windows Server 2016 VM, it creates a few l2bridge networks by itself. I need to understand why it does this, and how I can prevent it from doing it.

Here is an example in PowerShell:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                                                               DRIVER              SCOPE
ca219b21052e        7801716e9583cad0ba3ed1485f31565c458137a6e4f40cca94843ba2832df54a   l2bridge            local
f5f624883546        baa71d645232fc8af24bab5be539c72834b5a4242f50f5c74b63e6232087a68c   l2bridge            local
b3fc9850bded        bea5e6edfeee221543be2d04f302974e55684dd969a0f4876e4f56126bcc7069   l2bridge            local
9c842e81e14c        c0785dea1abcaac43a253b0c1486ad83c163deb8773a93a38b61cec49b5a6fef   l2bridge            local
a79de5fb36a2        dbbd1fb27d805f460e87db6146a10e97961434e5a0d8747c81b1e5d3961d3340   l2bridge            local
8149a6d53b76        efecb0a306cc5f27d1a7de2c86715d10e353aff28a72da524d830da1fc629b2c   l2bridge            local
f247c7ba98d0        nat                                                                nat                 local
987a17d6b0c9        none                                                               null                local
PS C:\Users\Administrator> docker network rm $(docker network ls -q)
ca219b21052e
f5f624883546
b3fc9850bded
9c842e81e14c
a79de5fb36a2
8149a6d53b76
Error response from daemon: nat is a pre-defined network and cannot be removed
Error response from daemon: none is a pre-defined network and cannot be removed
PS C:\Users\Administrator> docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
f247c7ba98d0        nat                 nat                 local
987a17d6b0c9        none                null                local
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Stop-Service docker
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Start-Service docker
WARNING: Waiting for service 'docker (Docker)' to start...
WARNING: Waiting for service 'docker (Docker)' to start...
WARNING: Waiting for service 'docker (Docker)' to start...
WARNING: Waiting for service 'docker (Docker)' to start...
WARNING: Waiting for service 'docker (Docker)' to start...
WARNING: Waiting for service 'docker (Docker)' to start...
WARNING: Waiting for service 'docker (Docker)' to start...
PS C:\Users\Administrator> docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                                                               DRIVER              SCOPE
0376f6b22711        7801716e9583cad0ba3ed1485f31565c458137a6e4f40cca94843ba2832df54a   l2bridge            local
0d4c458937b3        baa71d645232fc8af24bab5be539c72834b5a4242f50f5c74b63e6232087a68c   l2bridge            local
6b6df27f9900        bea5e6edfeee221543be2d04f302974e55684dd969a0f4876e4f56126bcc7069   l2bridge            local
3edc036ec10a        c0785dea1abcaac43a253b0c1486ad83c163deb8773a93a38b61cec49b5a6fef   l2bridge            local
b5205dae811c        dbbd1fb27d805f460e87db6146a10e97961434e5a0d8747c81b1e5d3961d3340   l2bridge            local
2fbb193b5d3c        efecb0a306cc5f27d1a7de2c86715d10e353aff28a72da524d830da1fc629b2c   l2bridge            local
fd67e0d563f4        nat                                                                nat                 local
830c63dbbab7        none                                                               null                local
```

I'm running Docker version 17.03.1-ee-3, build 3fcee33.

Update:
Here is the output for the docker network inspect:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> docker network inspect 859d73d47265
[
    {
        "Name": "f03805eacff6242bcd2b542c2b43dc203028268734fe5bd4cff5bd9ab924169a",
        "Id": "859d73d4726589c7167adb968e9a2338604ffc0033b43b95b092feeafd692785",
        "Created": "2017-11-01T13:01:35.7797185+02:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "l2bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "windows",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "192.168.0.0/24",
                    "Gateway": "192.168.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Containers": {},
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.windowsshim.hnsid": "533b975d-f6a3-47d3-887c-8286096e67e4",
            "com.docker.network.windowsshim.networkname": "f03805eacff6242bcd2b542c2b43dc203028268734fe5bd4cff5bd9ab9241
69a"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

Comment: what is the output of `docker ps` after you start the service?

Comment: Hi, this is the output:

`PS C:\Users\Administrator> docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             
STATUS              PORTS
NAMES
PS C:\Users\Administrator>`

Comment: Do a inspect on one of the networks and post that in your question. `docker network inspect 0376f6b22711`